# What is Best practice in objective c for creating an object and setting its properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, enums

Considering I have a `UIViewController` called `ErrorViewController` that I am instantiating using `initWithNibName`.

There is a enum on this `ErrorViewController` describing its "type".

This `ErrorViewController` has one delegate function that returns to its delegate which will respond according to the type set on the `ErrorViewController`.

Is it better to pass all the parameters within a new `initWithNibName` function, and set private properties on the `ErrorViewController`.  Like this:

```
ErrorViewController *errorVc = [[ErrorViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"ErrorViewController" bundle:nil 
andErrorType:kErrorTypeA andDelegate:self];

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
andErrorType:(ErrorType)errorType andDelegate:(id<ErrorDelegate>)delegate{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = delegate;
        self.errorType = errorType;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Or is it better to instantiate the object and afterward set its public properties like this:

```
ErrorViewController *errorVc = [[ErrorViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"ErrorViewController" bundle:nil];
errorVc.delegate = self;
errorVc.type = kErrorTypeA.
```

And regarding the delegate method, is it best practice to check the type by passing a parameter, or by checking the property of the passed back Controller as follows:

```
- (void)ErrorPage:(ErrorViewController *)ErrorPage 
// check ErrorPage.errorType
}
```

or this: ?

```
- (void)ErrorPage:(ErrorViewController *)ErrorPage 
andErrorType:(ErrorType)errorType
// check errorType
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a question of preference. If the object can't function correctly without error-type and/or delegate, it's probably best to provide your custom initialiser.

As to your second question, I would provide the error type as in your second example. Note that the method name should start with a lowercase character though (`-errorPage:` instead of `-ErrorPage:`).

Additionally, if you use it a lot, I would provide a convenience class method to create the object:

```
+(ErrorViewController*) standardErrorViewControllerWithErrorType: (ErrorType) errorType andDelegate: (id<ErrorDelegate>) delegate {

  ErrorViewController *evc = [[ErrorViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"ErrorViewController" bundle: nil andErrorType: errorType andDelegate: delegate];
return evc;
}
```

**Edit**

Also, in your init method, it is encouraged to use `-(instancetype) init...` instead of `-(id) init....`

Comment: Also, "and" is really used in method names anymore.  (Ie. Use delegate instead of andDelegate. )

Comment: That's right (guess you mean "is NOT really used") ! I also wanted to point that out but gathered its just personal preference and so adhered to the OPs style.

Comment: A lot of "best practice" stuff regarding this ans imilar questions can be found [here](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/)

Comment: Actually, I meant to say "is rarely used" but auto-correct got me, lol!

Comment: @Mario, great direction, and Filip, going to read that, actually that was something I was looking to get my hands on for a while.